# How to make Jersey Unit test for Post method

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey, jax-rs

### Questions

How do create a Jersey Unit Test for a POST?

How do I add post parameters?

### What I tried

For a GET it is easy (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html):

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String hello = target("hello").request().get(String.class);
        assertEquals("Hello World!", hello);
    }
```

For a post it is more diffuse. I managed to get the response object, but how do I get the actual response object (the String)?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Response r = target("hello").request().post(Entity.json("test"));
    System.out.println(r.toString());
}
```

Result: `InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:9998/hello, status=200, reason=OK}}`

Comment: Use `r.readEntity(String.class)` to get the JSON String, or use your POJO class if you have one set up

Comment: @peeskillet how do i add post params?

Comment: If by post params you mean `x-www-form-urlencoded`, create a `Form`. Use its `param` method to add. Then post `Entity.form`. You should look at the client api documentation. It in the jersey guide you linked to

Comment: @peeskillet The problem I'm getting now is that my `@WebListener` is not being invoked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Path("hello")
public static class HelloResource {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String doPost(Map<String, String> data) {
        return "Hello " + data.get("name") + "!";
    }

}

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
}

@Test
public void testPost() {
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    data.put("name", "popovitsj");

    final String hello = target("hello")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.json(data), String.class);

    assertEquals("Hello popovitsj!", hello);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be easy.

Comment: How do I add post params? What you're doing here is sending the parameters as json.

Comment: If you need send data as JSON, you should send one object with all parameters (map or entity) and add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` annotation. In case if you need multiple separate parameters you should send the form and use `@FormParam("paramname")` for each parameter. `@FormParam("firstName") String firstName, @FormParam("lastName") String lastName`